# New computer running Windows 10 and old SSD running Ubuntu 16.04 and old HDD running Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I've a new Dell XPS 8920, running on Windows 10.
I've installed SSD from my old system, which ran on Ubuntu 16.04, and an HDD, which has Windows 7 installed.

My new PC boots fine with Windows 10.

I've run boot-repair, which created this: [Paste Ubuntu](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24520230/)

IS there any way to reinstall grub2 or something to get the grub menu for all three drives to boot?

Comment: The reason that you're running into problems is because Windows 7 and Ubuntu are most likely installed in BIOS-MBR mode, but Windows 10 is most certainly installed in UEFI mode.

Comment: You can change the boot order to Ubuntu as first. and then update your grub. This should solve your problem. As mentioned in  Android Dev comment, mode of installation is different, then both cant go along.

Comment: Let me clarify that I have the drives installed but that the boot process only goes directly to Windows 10. hunch are you suggesting that I change from UEFI to Legacy mode when booting?